# SSL Sharing on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, ssl, share

Im trying to share a wildcard SSL cert across many applications.  The way it would work is users would have websites with thier domain, but when they need a secure connection they would be redirected to a designated SSL site like https://client422.domain.com

Can session data be shared across the domains even if I place both domains on a single site and a single App Pool?

Comment: i'd say this is sortof a openssl.exe issue (and session issue with software coding), and so i'd say its ok and belongs in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog article on creating a wildcard cert with OpenSSL (although the article could have a typo or two in the openssl config part, if you figure out the config, it will work as far as the openssl commands are concerned).

http://codingathome.blogspot.com/2008/11/creating-self-signed-certificate.html

If my article is too difficult, and if you have linux available, i've heard that tinyCA is the way to go.

Now, as far as 'session data' sharing goes, thats a whole different ball of wax.  I'd say its possible if you store session data on server side.